# jqGrid hover over icon with empty string

Tags: jqgrid, mousehover

I have a column with Actions which contains icons. One of the icon ( second icon) is tied to qtip. So when I hover over it shows the empty div which looks bad.  It is jqGrid's hover over element value. But as in actions i do not have any value it shows blank.

What i can do to disable it for that particular column ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your colModel options, you can specify title:false like this:

```
colModel: [
            { name: "Actions", title: false },
            { name: "Type", index: "Type" },
            { name: "ReceiptLoc", index: "ReceiptLoc" }
        ],
```

That empty little box you are seeing is the tooltip copy of text in the cell. Your Action column has no bound values in the cell, that is why it is empty.